# Full-page body in Chrome print-to-pdf: omit area reserved for header and footer?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-headless

I don't want to *just* suppress/disable the running header and footer *text*. I'm already setting the following CSS:

```css
@page {
  size: 6.6in 4.25in;
  margin: 0;
}
```

(yes, I'm setting a custom page size)

`--print-to-pdf-no-header` does not do what I'm asking for.

I'm guessing that, "under the covers", Chrome defines a page layout for printing to PDF that includes fixed areas for the header and footer. I want to override that page layout to omit those areas; to omit those currently unusable strips of white space across the top and bottom of the page. I want the body to occupy the full area of the page.

I'd prefer to do this via a `chrome --headless --print-to-pdf` command line, but I'm prepared to use another method if necessary (Puppeteer?).

I'm running Chrome 100.0.4896.60 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10.

Update (2022-04-28): If I use an SVG (.svg) file as input, rather than HTML, then I can make the SVG occupy the entire space (although, it's finicky tweaking the page width and height to correspond to the viewBox extents). But with an HTML file (I've zero'd all margins, padding in the HTML CSS), those top and bottom margins stubbornly remain in the PDF: I can't fit as much on the PDF page as I can with SVG input.

Comment: Related tip that might be of interest to anyone interested in this question: to set the background color of the PDF page, use CSS to set the background-color property of the html element (html. not body).

Comment: Further to that tip: if you're using SVG, not HTML, as the input, to set the background color of the PDF page, use CSS in the SVG to set the background-color property of the svg element.

Answer (score 0):

I took onboard your comment about html colouring, however note it is not visible in the html, nor print preview at top, nor used via snippet (unless you switch background ON), but is certainly visible in the `--headless` PDF printout page.

I also used a different size for demo, and threw in a print button for those that like them, delete or hide as desired.

NOTE: there are no margins, the top line of text has natural leading (above and below) that cannot be normally removed (without fettling) even though there is spill over at end of line where the `!` width exceeds page boundary!

[image]

```js
const buttonPrintOrSaveDocument = document.querySelector(
    ".button-print-or-save-document"
);
function printOrSave() {
    window.print();
}
buttonPrintOrSaveDocument.addEventListener("click", printOrSave);
```

```css
@media print { @page {
    size: 125px 100px ;
    margin: 0!important; } body { margin: 0!important;} html { background-color: lightblue;}}
```

```html
Hello&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;World!

<br><button class="button-print-or-save-document">Print or Save Document</button>
```

If you set the demo height to 53px you will see there is no margin all round
[image]

[image]