# Why are there missing spaces in SVG text in some browsers?

Tags: svg

I'm drawing a graphic in CorelDRAW (2021) and then exporting it to SVG.

In CorelDRAW, one of the artistic text objects contains text in different font weights. For example:

> **Garfield** sat on the mat

**Problem:** Some browsers, such as Chrome and Edge, display that text in the SVG as:

> **Garfield**sat on the mat

That is, with the bold "Garfield" abutting the normal "sat", with no space.

In other browsers, such as Firefox, the same SVG displays as expected, with a space.

Example SVG (exported from CorelDRAW: not a truly minimal example, but I've stripped some of the excess markup):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<!-- Creator: CorelDRAW 2021.5 -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" width="3.44562in" height="0.247335in" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 18928.2 1358.7">
 <defs>
  <style type="text/css">
   <![CDATA[
    .fil0 {fill:#373435}
    .fnt1 {font-weight:normal;font-size:1831.1px;font-family:'Arial'}
    .fnt0 {font-weight:bold;font-size:1831.1px;font-family:'Arial'}
   ]]>
  </style>
 </defs>
 <text x="-87.9" y="1334.9"  class="fil0 fnt0">Garfield</text>
 <text x="6831.7" y="1334.9"  class="fil0 fnt1"> sat on the mat</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, @RobertLongson: done. I've added example SVG as a runnable code snippet. I was curious to see whether the SVG would work by itself as a code snippet, or whether I would have to enclose it in HTML markup, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome and Edge, and possibly other browsers, ignore leading spaces inside the SVG `<text>` element.

Here's a snippet of the SVG:

```
<text ... class="fil4 fnt0">Garfield</text>
<text ... class="fil4 fnt1"> sat on the mat</text>
```

(where "..." indicates elided attributes)

Note:

- CorelDRAW has split the original single text object into two SVG `<text>` elements. Understandable, because of the different font weights (`.fnt0` is bold, `.fnt1` is normal).
- The content of the second `<text>` element begins with a space.

**Workaround:** In CorelDRAW, don't mix font weights in a single text object.

More generally, whatever application you use to create SVG: if you notice a missing space when the SVG is rendered (say, in a browser), check whether the content of the corresponding SVG `<text>` element begins with a leading space. If so, rework your artwork in the original application to avoid that SVG output.

Comment: So: some "SVG renderers" (Chrome, Edge) ignore that leading space; others (Firefox; Antenna House Formatter, for PDF output) honor it. What is the "correct" behavior (say, according to the SVG spec)? Not a rhetorical question; I just haven't taken the time to investigate the answer yet. This is one reason why I haven't investigated whether this is a known bug in, say, Chromium; perhaps ignoring the leading space is correct behavior, by design.

Answer (score 0):

Usually for html2pdf, in common with many apps, heavy weight texts tend to "stretch" into a following void, or in this case the leading space is not defined. One way to enforce whitespace is try `&nbsp;` in standard html see the enforced spacing in https://stackoverflow.com/a/74297349/10802527

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<!-- Creator: CorelDRAW 2021.5 -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" width="3.44562in" height="0.247335in" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 18928.2 1358.7">
 <defs>
  <style type="text/css">
   <![CDATA[
    .fil0 {fill:#373435}
    .fnt1 {font-weight:normal;font-size:1831.1px;font-family:'Arial'}
    .fnt0 {font-weight:bold;font-size:1831.1px;font-family:'Arial'}
   ]]>
  </style>
 </defs>
 <text x="-87.9" y="1334.9"  class="fil0 fnt0">Garfield</text>
 <text x="6831.7" y="1334.9"  class="fil0 fnt1">&nbsp;sat on the mat</text>
</svg>
```